# Promises.all how to ensure all have promises are available?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, axios

I have taken this example from the Axios AJAX library but the same goes for `Promises.all()`.

So far I have read you can use `Promises.all()` to check if all promises from an array of promises have been resolved.

This is really neat but what happens if you push a promise and it resolves before the next one has been pushed?

I am guessing with the overhead of my average AJAX call of at least 50ms the push will always happen before any ajax requests but to just say taken for this granted does not really feel right.

There are 2 solutions for this that I could think of:

1. Use a count to ensure both(in thise case) AJAX requests are in the
   array.
2. Check for the actual function names being there.

How are others dealing with this or are most people simply satisfied with the hope of both AJAX requests being pushed before a single one can be resolved quick enough.

```
axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Are you dynamically building the array of promises? Or are you wondering if the requests might somehow finish before they're wrapped?

Comment: Yes these promises are being pushed from multiple places. Let's say a single promise has been pushed while I would expect 2 promises then theoretically this single promise could trigger a then before the second one has been pushed? If that is the case there needs to be a mechanism to check for this beforehand no?

Comment: You don't need a mechanism to check this beforehand. `Promise.all` makes a single promise from an array of promises. How do you mean they are being pushed from different places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to worry about promises that resolve before they are passed to `Promise.all`: `Promise.all` will not be called before its (array) argument has been completely evaluated. Only when the array is ready, will `Promise.all` be called.

Whether or not any of those promises is already resolved, at the time `Promise.all` is called, is really not important. `Promise.all` will check which ones are in a resolved state, and will only call its `then` method when all of them have been fulfilled. It might even be that *all* the promises in the array are already fulfilled: no problem, as soon as `Promise.all` is executed, it will schedule the execution of the `then` method. Even the time during which those promises were already resolved does not matter. Even if they were resolved one hour ago, `Promise.all` will still do its job correctly.

Comment: I don't want to check if the promise has been resolved since this information is self contained within the promise and indeed `Promise.all()` will check this for me. I want to ensure that `Promises.all()` does not fire when I might not have pushed all promises in my array that I want. But according to the answer of @fatman the `sync` operation of a `push` will always happen before any `async` request even triggers. So I guess this is no longer a concern. Thanks for your insight though, appreciate it.

Comment: Your array will be complete when you pass it to `Promise.all`. My point is that there is no way to get an incomplete array passed to `Promise.all` (unless you do this on purpose of course, and modify the array *after* calling `Promise.all`). JavaScript always evaluates the argument first before calling the function to which the argument is passed.

Comment: Ok so the interpreter goes over the entire code and knows exactly when the last item has been pushed onto this array. Therefore it knows the argument has been completely evaluated and will make sure to only call `Promise.all` at that point? I am guessing the whole `async/sync` story still applies here but the evaulation of being done before this? It is just hard to comprehend because I don't know exactly how the interpreter decides when the push statement has completely evaluated.

Comment: It is a bit hard to talk about `push` when your question does not include code with a `push`. Instead you have an array literal with two values. What I am saying is that the JavaScript engine will first evaluate each of the array elements (from left to right), which evaluate to two promises, and then will wrap those two values into an array, and then will call `Promise.all`. This principle has nothing to do with `Promise.all`. It is the same with `a = [].concat([1+1, 5-3, 8*2]);`: the arithmetic is done first, then the array is created with those results, and then `concat` is executed.

Comment: True. In my code example I have two values but in my codebase this will be an empty array where components will push their promises into so there will be no initial array elements. I am still guessing javascript interprets my entire codebase and still knows when all `push` operations are done though?

Comment: But I assume you first push all promises to your array, and only *then* call `Promise.all` on that array? It is hard to talk about code I cannot see.

Comment: No, thats the entire point I push multiple promises to an array but I don't know exactly when the array contains all the necessary items. Judging by your comment I guess I have to ensure that my array is filled with the right amount of promises before I should call `Promise.all`? If I have 3 ajax requests I have to ensure my array contains 3 items before I even call `Promise.all`?

Comment: Yes, you should first build the array. Unless that in itself is *also* asynchronous, that should not be a problem. You really should update your question, and explain exactly how you build your array and when you decide to invoke `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

[`Axios.all` calls `Promise.all`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/v0.16.2/lib/axios.js#L44) which returns a single promise which resolves *when all the promises in the iterable argument are resolved*.

`Axios.spread` will be getting the resolved values from `getUserAccount` and `getUserPermission`.

Answer (score 0):

Push is a sync operation, ajax is async. JS will always run all sync operations before running any async operation even if it has already finished. for example:

```
for (i=0;i<10000000;i++){
  console.log('looping');
}

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('running async')
}, 0)
```

Although the timeout is set to 0, so it can immediately run, it will wait until the for loop is done and only then run the async operation.

So even if you push a promise and it immediately resolves, it will wait until the push is done and only then will react to the resolved promises.

Comment: Wow, I will test this out and read up on it. If this is true then `Promises.all()` is a brilliant solution to dealing with multiple AJAX requests. Golden answer right there.

Comment: Although the explanation of async and sync is correct, this is not the reason why a `push` is evaluated first: it is because this is the proper order of evaluation in JavaScript: an argument (array in this case) must first be completely evaluated before the function (to which this argument is passed, i.e. `Promise.all`) is executed (also synchronously). So this has little to do with asynchronous code.